# Share cookies between WebBrowser and IE

Tags: webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

I open Internet Explorer 11. Log in to website. Then I create WebBrowser control. Navigate to same site. But cookies are missed, I am not logged in. Possible to share cookies between IE and WebBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser uses IE under the hood but older version by default. In order to use newer you'll need to adjust the registry. In order to retrieve cookies:

```
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref uint pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);
    const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;

    public static string GetGlobalCookies(string uri)
    {
        uint datasize = 1024;
        StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)datasize);
        if (InternetGetCookieEx(uri, null, cookieData, ref datasize, 
        INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero)
            && cookieData.Length > 0)
        {
            return cookieData.ToString().Replace(';', ',');
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[Source](http://ycouriel.blogspot.com/2010/07/webbrowser-and-httpwebrequest-cookies.html)

Then you can pass them to web browser control like this:

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Document.Cookie = GetGlobalCookies(uri);
```